# Checking 7z Enrypted file status

Tags: java, 7zip

I am trying to manipulate 7z file using Java. I want to check whether 7z archive is password protected or not. I am using `sevenzipjbind` library. 
I could not get help from [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=add&group_id=210915&atid=1015661), because it is down for maintainance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the `ISevenZipInArchive` and can check if it has the property `ENCRYPTED`